# how to load image into canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I have a canvas with a blue circle.
I want to display the image I want to load instead. How can I implement this more correctly?

```
 const canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
  const radius = 24
  canvas.width = radius * 2
  canvas.height = canvas.width
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d")
  if (context) {
    context.beginPath()
    context.arc(radius, radius, radius, -Math.PI, Math.PI / 2)
    context.lineTo(0, radius * 2)
    context.closePath()
    context.clip()
    context.fillStyle = "white"
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    context.beginPath()
    context.arc(radius, radius, radius * 0.75, 0, Math.PI * 2)
    context.clip()
    context.fillStyle = "#0066FF"
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    context.beginPath()
    context.font = "18px Inter"
    context.fillStyle = "white"
    context.fillText(size, 18, radius + 6)
    context.clip()
  }
```

[test link img](https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1160/1160358.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can actually draw any image on to the canvas. But if you have a really simple shape like a sphere in your case then I would just do it the other way.

```
const image = new Image();
image.src = "path";
image.onload = () => ctx.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
```

Before drawing the image you need to wait for it to load so in the example I add an event listener to draw the image whenever it loads. But you can also preload the image and then draw it anytime.